# How to read inline styling of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, inline, styling

I'd like to know if it's possible to determine what **inline styling** has been attributed to an HTML element.  I do not need to retrieve the value, but rather just detect if it's been set inline or not.

For instance, if the HTML were:

```
<div id="foo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green;"></div>
```

How can I determine that `width`, `height`, and `background` have been explicitly declared, inline?

As far as I can tell, the solution can work two ways.  I can ask it if a specific attribute is set and it will tell me true or false, or it can tell me all attributes that have been set.  Like so:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('foo');
obj.hasInlineStyle('width');  //returns true;
obj.hasInlineStyle('border'); //returns false;

//or

obj.getInlineStyles();   //returns array with values:
                       // 'width' 'height' and 'background'
```

I'm not interested in css attributes that are inherited via declarations in a stylesheet, only inline styles.  One last thing, I have no control over the HTML source.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to work with IE**

You could try something like this

```
function hasInlineStyle(obj, style) {
    var attrs = obj.getAttribute('style');
    if(attrs === null) return false;
    if(typeof attrs == 'object') attrs = attrs.cssText;
    var styles = attrs.split(';');
    for(var x = 0; x < styles.length; x++) {
        var attr = styles[x].split(':')[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").toLowerCase();
        if(attr == style) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if you have an element like this:

```
<span id='foo' style='color: #000; line-height:20px;'></span>
```

That also has a stylesheet like this:

```
#foo { background-color: #fff; }
```

The function would return...

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
alert(hasInlineStyle(foo,'color')); // true
alert(hasInlineStyle(foo,'background-color')); // false
```

Comment: I was just looking through jQuery... looks like they insert stylesheet values as well (unacceptable in this case).  Nice solution, though :)

Comment: And the .attr('style') doesn't include stylesheet declarations in jQuery, only those set through style="" in the document.

Comment: Wait... disregard that last comment

Comment: One last thing.. the null case (where getAttribute('style') is null)

Comment: Beautiful.. I really appreciate it.  I'm not so great with RegEx, what's that RegEx do?  Trim?

And now the real challenge... weird css attributes like "border" and "border-left."

Comment: Yeah, the regex trims. What about "border" and "border-left"? The function should still work for them.

Comment: Do you mean you want border-left to return true if border was specified?

Comment: This seems to cause trouble in IE... I think .getAttribute("style") returns an object rather than a string

Comment: Yeah, border-left should return true if border is set... but I've found a way around this so no worries.

Comment: One IE quirk that you need to be aware of... if the element has an inline style of "border: 1px solid #000;" IE will say it has "border-left" "border-right" "border-top" "border-bottom" but not "border"... however, getting it to recognize these things is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The style property of an HTML Element returns a style object which lists all the properties.  Any that have a value (other than null or empty string) have been set on the inline style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try doing something like:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("foo");
var obj_has_background = (obj.style.background != "");
var obj_has_width = (obj.style.width != "");
var obj_has_height = (obj.style.height != "");
```

Seems a bit long, but this is the best (and shortest) solution I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if a certain styling attribute exists, or just want a list of the possible attributes?
If you already know the attribute, then you can just use

```
hasStyle(obj,'width');
function hasStyle(obj, style)
{
     switch(style)
         case 'width':
              return obj.style.width ? true : false;
         case 'background':
              return obj.style.background ? true : false;
}
```

You can use Paolo's function to generate an array of the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that return local element style definitions:

```
function getLocalStyle(pEleId, pStyle) {
    var camelStyle = camelCase( pStyle );
    var eleStyles = document.getElementById(pEleId).style
    return eleStyles[camelStyle];
}

function camelCase(str) {
  return str
    .split('-')
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + b.slice(1));
}
```

Usage:

```
var backgroundColor = getLocalStyle( pLayerName, "background-color" );
```