# detect inline background style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, inline

I have a `<div>` that on occasion has an inline `background` attribute applied to it.

I would like to be able to check if there is an *inline* style attached to it, and if there is then I want to go ahead and attach a `background-position`.

Is there a way that I can check explictly for inline backgrounds applied to `$(this)`?

```
if ($(this).css('background').length > 0) { 
   console.log('has a background'); 
   // set a background position
   $(this).css('background-position', 'center 22px');
}
```

Comment: you could parse through the value of the style-attribute of the element

Comment: What do you mean by "inline" : not defined into CSS class?

Comment: @sdespont Yes, inline is when it is defined in the markup, i.e. `style="background: url('www.crmpicco.co.uk');"`

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476730/how-to-read-inline-styling-of-an-element?rq=1

Comment: Ok, but can't you apply your background-position in all cases?

Comment: @sdespont No, only in certain cases - as not always is there a background on the element.

Comment: I've heard of `display:inline` but never of `inline background`
Is it the `rep-x` property you're talking about?

Comment: @kidwon There's no `display: inline;` involved here, I am referring to inline styling. Inline styling = http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm

Comment: Yeah, 10x I got what you had meant.

Comment: @corvec Thanks, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for. The answer provided works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet something like this might work

```
if($(this).attr("style").indexOf("background") >=0){
  //we have inline background styles!
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Chris. That worked exactly like I hoped it would!

Answer (score 1):

You can test for inline styles using `prop`

```
if ($(this).prop('style').backgroundImage) {
  //.. do what you want to
}
```

Comment: @crmpicco just ran into it myself, the style prop actually allows for a much nicer approach. And I thought it would return a string. Edited the answer.

Comment: thx! `$(this).prop('style').backgroundImage` gives e.g. "_url(http ://example.com/images/img.jpg)_"